# No module named 'selenium' error

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium

I'm very new at this so thank you for your patience.

when I try

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

the response is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named 'selenium'
```

I've installed selenium both by using `sudo easy_install selenium` and by executing the `.py` installation, however I think that it is installing selenium to the python 2.7 that comes standard on a mac. Is there a simple way to install a module through IDLE in Python 3.5.1 that I am not seeing? Again this works fine through terminal but it seems to be putting selenium in the local/bin.

Thanks again in advance

Comment: Where are your other packages installed? And are you using virtualenv?

Comment: Do you have `easy_install3` or something similar? You could also try `python3 -m pip install selenium`

Comment: You may also have a `pip3` program. You can debug your issue by running `python2` and then `import selenium`. If it succeeds, your OS defaults to the python 2.x series.

Comment: Thanks, python3 -m pip install selenium worked.

Answer (score 0):

The Main location for python is C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32
UserName, will be your windows user

But for Output the code  is run on Microsoft Visual Studios folder in
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64

so copy (Lib)  folder from the main location to microsoft visual studios . 
This error will not appear next time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Your answer adds very little to the original question and the comments given.